# Does proving P^NP = NP have an implication in the P=NP question?

Tags: complexity-theory, oracle-machines

For language $O$, by $P^O$ I am referring to the set containing every language that can be decided by a polynomial-time deterministic TM with oracle access to $O$ (see Arora and Barak, Chapter 3, definition 3.5).

Comment: It implies NP=coNP.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus: Oh, yes. I came across a similar setting when learning Cook reductions and its lack of sensitivity to the NP and coNP difference.

Fair enough. NP = coNP does not imply P = NP. Thanks for replying.